# Area of loop defined by parametric equations

Tags: calculus, area

My textbook says if $x=f(t)$ and $y=g(t)$ then area bounded by the curve from $x = a$ to $x = b$ is integral of $\int{g(t)}{f^{'}}{(t)}{dt}$ in some interval ($\alpha$, $\beta$)...
Then it says this integral is also equal to integral of $\int{f(t)}{g'(t)}{dt}$ in the same interval with opposite sign. I am not getting how this integral is same as the previous. Help me with an intuition or method how this is possible.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps if you can provided a picture of the textbook, or perhaps how alpha and beta are defined, it would help in providing a bit more context.

Comment: This is just Green's theorem.

Comment: @Element118 alpha and beta are f inverse of a and b

Comment: @Parcly Taxel please explain me bit more